# Is there any benifit of ActionBarSherlock if my app run using android 4 and above

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I was using ActionBarSherlock  to make my app run with app version of android and use actionbar, but now I don't need to support the old version and it is enough for me to support 4 and above , is there any benefit of ActionBarSherlock still for my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Feel free to use the native API Level 11+ implementation of the action bar.

Note, though, that some things in Android may steer you in the direction of using an action bar backport... though the `appcompat` one published by Google, not ActionBarSherlock. For example, the recommended version of `MediaRouteActionButton` requires the `appcompat` action bar, though I am maintaining [a port that works with the regular action bar](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter).